# `TypeError: Couldn't build proto file into descriptor pool: duplicate symbol 'edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.Language'` while importing corenlp in Python

Tags: stanford-nlp

`TypeError: Couldn't build proto file into descriptor pool: duplicate symbol 'edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.Language'`

I am getting this error for this code in Python:
`import corenlp`

I've been on this issue for over 5 hours now, I am just not able to import corenlp in python for some reason. I have followed all the steps:

1. `pip install corenlp`
2. I also installed `protobuf` and added it to my path as some solution said that.
3. My Stanford CoreNLP library version is 4.5.1 which is compatible with the corenlp library.

I am guessing there's some issue with protobuf. Let me know if anybody can fix this!